# Website has huge whitespace on right side of the page and of the header when the page is resized to a smaller width

Tags: html, css, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have tried a lot of solutions listed here in stackoverflow, but I couldn't solve this issue.. this is a wordpress website. http://www.delice-ikbal.com/

I have tried to remove any margin or padding from the `<html>` and `<body>` It didn't help.

I've also tried something like :

```
html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

`overflow-x: hidden` of course doesn't allow to scroll horizontaly.. so the content is not visible totally when the page width is getting smaller

So I would like to remove the white space existing on the header and the right side of the page.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on browser/behaviours we need to replicate in order to see this bug?

Comment: @leaksterrr : thks. I've updated my question with a screenshot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of containers with hardcoded width in px.

Remove max-width: 1080px in .main-navigation, it's the container which cause the issue.

EDIT: and in div.nav-menu > ul

```
ul.nav-menu, div.nav-menu > ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0 40px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Apparently it's not the issue.

Comment: Yes it is, remove 1080px in div.nav-menu > ul, the issue has moved

Answer (score 0):

Use this css

```css
.site-header {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: rgb(36, 17, 0);
    min-width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solves the header issue, but not the margin in the right of the page. Any idea ? Thank you :)